# Restrict sccess to SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am completely new to SQL and have basically no knowledge on how to do what I'm after.  I have created a database (RandomGenerator) and at present all user have access to view all the tables, stored procedures, etc.

What I'm after is only allowing access to the database for myself and one other user.

I have read many threads and websites but I can't figure out how to restrict access to all other users for this current up and running database.

On my instance on SQL Server, there are many other databases which obviously I don't want to restrict access for.

I don't want any other user to be able to view anything under my 'RandomGenerator' database.

Do I need some sort of script or something or can it be done in permissions or something like that?

Comment: You need to learn about granting permissions.  The place to start is the documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx.

Comment: From my experience it's rather unusual that a newly created database is accessible by all users on this server by default. Have you checked permissions by right clicking the database, selecting "Properties" and then "Permissions"?

Comment: @papatoob I have already done that and there are no users listed in the 'Users or Roles' table.

Comment: Then all your users (server logins) are sysadmins, which is not good. You should remove sysadmin role from your logins and allow their access only to specific databases. To retain users full access to their databases you can set their database roles as db_owner, although this is not good design either; better is to create some roles with correct access pattern and assign users to your roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users shouldn't have access to the database, that sounds like all the existing logins have System Admin access, which is a bad idea. If they were set up correctly, they would not have access by default to your new database.

You can setup permissions in the security tab of the database you have and could add "deny" permissions to the other users but if the existing users are system admins, they can probably change all that anyway!

Somebody should 'own' the SQL server and have the necessary skills to setup all the other users correctly otherwise you are probably wasting your time.